# C# Core Web API controller optional Array default value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have a controller with method GetAll which has all params optional (with default value). Concept is to make any of these requests valid:

```
/crm/contacts
/crm/contacts?sort=created_by
/crm/contacts?search=My%20Customer
/crm/contacts?sort=created_by&take=100
/crm/contacts?from=10&take=100
/crm/contacts?search=My%20Customer&sort=created_by&take=100
```

Code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public async Task<DTO.CRM.contact[]> GetAllAsync(
     int? from = null,
     int? take = 10,
     string search = null,
     string[] sort = null)
{
```

In debug, I would suspect sort to be null, instead, I see it as a {string[0]}. I use dotnet core 2.1.4 on macOS.

How can I get sort really null if it is not passed in url?

Comment: Does it matter? Either way (empty string array or null) you have no values on which to sort.

Comment: Not really, I can handle both alternatives easily, I am just wondering why array is resolved as empty string when it is not even mentioned in URL and therefore should be set = null

Comment: because default empty string array is safer than null.

Comment: Nkosi: arguable. If I expect param to be null, I will handle it as null, not empty string. From my point of view declaring something to be null (string[] sort = null) and in next step handling it as empty string ( if (sort.length == 0) ) may cause in NullReferenceException especially if .NET changes behaviour (which is not that rare to be honest)

Comment: You still check for null. (defensive coding) `if(sort != null && sort.Length > 0)`. I see your point though, that is the default behavior of the framework. Well, unless you create a custom binder for that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a [custom binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1) if that really bugs you. However, it's probably not worth it and I would suggest you keep your code safe - make sure it handles `null`, empty arrays and non-empty arrays with null or empty strings.

Comment: Thanks. Though, I will implement defensive coding as you and Nkosi mentioned.